# MongoDB storing arrays of ObjectId's

Tags: mongodb, foreign-keys, objectid

In my database I have to store an array of object ids. What should I use? Something like this:

```
[ObjectId("50350e12a36feb1be6000364"), ObjectId("57350e12a37fef1be6000922"), ObjectId("10350e17d34ffb1be6200925")]
```

or something like this:

```
["50350e12a36feb1be6000364", "57350e12a37fef1be6000922", "10350e17d34ffb1be6200925"]
```

I could save space with the second, and then cast to `ObjectId`, but am I loosing anything by using this approach? Do `ObjectId`s behave like foreign keys in relational databases?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would definitely go with the first approach, storing the `ObjectId`s directly. This saves space, as [`ObjectId` is 12 bytes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-TheBSONObjectIdDatatype) whereas the second approach string is 24 bytes.

Also, if the `ObjectId`s are used to fetch the objects later, storing as `ObjectId` saves some hassle.

Answer (score 11):

Unless you have a good reason not to, store them as an array of ObjectIds.  It's more compact (12 bytes vs. 24) and it more accurately reflects what's stored.  It can also enable driver-level support for following ObjectId references.

Comment: +1, Yeah, I think there is a basic misunderstanding about the size of ObjectIds in the question.